# Android & iOS library for playing windows media stream ( mms:// )

Tags: android, ios, mms, mms-gateway

I need to play windows media in android & iOS. I did searching, just found some commercial libraries.

Anyone know some free/open source library for playing mms:// in android & iOS ?

Comment: Do you solve this problem?